# Разбиение проекта на модули в GitHub

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github

Есть проект на GitHub (не оставляю ссылку, так как на картинке наглядней), структура проекта выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит структура проекта в IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на последней картинке специально изображена корневая папка проекта, так я хочу, что бы и на GitHub так было, к тому же в Intellij IDEA надо добавить новый модуль, в итоге на GitHub структура из модулей должна выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как так сделать?

Comment: На последней картинке нет вашего `automated-case-management-system`, поэтому она не объясняет, что вы хотите получить. Напишите словами.

Comment: Закинул вам [пулл-реквест](https://github.com/igorgorbunov3333/automated-case-management-system/pull/1).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за коммит! Проект на GitHub находится по адресу igorgorbunov3333/automated-case-management-system. Я хочу, к примеру, создать в этом каталоге новый - acms-engine, и в этот каталог закинуть все файлы и каталоги из первой картинки. Потом постепенно в в каталог igorgorbunov3333/automated-case-management-system будут добавляться новые модули на том же уровне, что и acms-engine.

Comment: Может, один из вариантов переместить каталог git из каталога E:\MyJavaProjects\automated-case-management-system в созданную папку E:\MyJavaProjects\automated-case-management-system\acms-engine? Но боюсь все испортить..

Comment: Смотрите: каталог, в котором находится каталог `.git`, называется корневым каталогом проекта. Версионируется всё, что в этом каталоге и подкаталогах (рекурсивно). Поэтому `.git` никуда не нужно перемещать, но можно перемещать всё, что вокруг. Если вы хотите разместить там сразу несколько проектов, создайте каталог под текущий и переместите туда всё, кроме `.git` и `.gitignore`.

Comment: То есть вы верное решение предполагаете. Перемещайте в подкаталог, снова `git add .; git commit -m'сообщение'`.

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание: [гитхаб не узнает автора первого коммита](https://github.com/igorgorbunov3333/automated-case-management-system/commits/master) (не ваш юзерпик на нем). Зайдите в настройки вашей учетки на гитхабе, добавьте как email alias ту почту, под которой вы делаете коммиты. Чтобы вспомнить эту почту, выполните команду `git config --global user.email`.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все ясно)